# Convert user input to regex

Tags: regex, expression, jsoup

I am working on a project where the user inputs a human readable search string with 
AND OR operators. 
I give three examples

1. a AND (b OR c)  ->  (?=.*\ba\b)(?=.*(\bb\b)|(\bc\b)).*
2. a OR (b AND c)
3. (a OR b) AND (c OR d)

The above are samples of the input I might get. 
I want to take that input and convert it to regex. 
Isn't this a sample of a compiler? Looking at it, I see
that what I want to do is convert a high level command
into a low level one. Do you have any suggestions on
how I could accomplish the above? What I want is, pass the
regex being produced to jsoup (pseudo selector :matchesOwn) 
and query an html document.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have nesting brackets like this `(()())((())())`, you cannot parse it with regex in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not want to parse input with regex, I want to convert it to regex. Instead of asking from the user to give me regex, I ask him a more human readable version of it.

Comment: How would you deal with the fact that regexs have order but search strings don't. if a user enters `foo AND bar` they expect `bar foo` to match which your example wont. Or are you going to generate every permutation.

Comment: Check again example 1. I've added the regex I want to produce.
I get the cursor back in the beginning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general way of  doing this is to make an intermediate representation in form of an easily traversable data structure. This is usually called an AST. If you're not familiar with the concept, have a look at [calculator-ast](http://util.io/calculator-ast) which does this transformation for a calculator language.

In order to turn the user input strings into ASTs, you need to use a parser. You could have a look at antlr. Personally I use v3, v4 seems to be less mature. Have a look at [antlr3.org](http://www.antlr3.org/). If you want to write the parser yourself, you could giva a [pratt parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_parser) a shot. This is not trivial and incorporating nice error handling takes time, but it can be a fun exercise.

Once you have an AST, turning it into a regex should be trivial by traversing the AST and outputting chars as you go along.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. So it is, in a very abstract way of thinking, a tiny compiler...

Comment: Yep! And such small languages are a great way of starting getting acquainted with compiler technologies and terminologies. Have fun.